# My glass material gets dark during rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I am currently working on a fake parfum/vodka commercial (realized too late into the process that parfum bottles are meant to have spray tops) but my liquid material gets really dark during rendering even though it is fine in the viewport.

I have attached both images for comparison. Preview [image: Preview]

And render

[image: Render]

And the liquid and bottle node setups

[image: Liquid node setup]

[image: Bottle node setup]

Nohting really complex. I'm using Cycles here.

Comment: hello maybe some faces are overlapping? Could you please share a part of your object (remove the useless parts)

Comment: Try to increase the maximum light bounces for everything (*Render Properties > Light Paths > Max Bounces*).

Comment: Check the Outliner for objects disabled for Viewport, but still enabled for rendering.

Comment: @moonboots Thanks, this was the problem. But I added Mr A's solution for good measure. [And here's the link to the blend file[](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bl8yH0P4-gtTJ8sePxEAaVJsROkuPSV2/view?usp=drive_link)  The models are basically the only thing in the file.

Comment: I can't check the file as it asks for an authorization ;)